# Django South and Constraint IDs

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south, database-migration

When creating unique and foreign key constraints, how does South come up with the ID for the constraint name, like:

```
CONSTRAINT report_type_id_refs_id_435782e833badd2f FOREIGN KEY (report_type_id)
REFERENCES reports_reporttype (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
```

The problem that I keep on hitting is that the migration tries to delete a constraint, but actual constraint in the database is different.

1. Does this hash get generated by South itself, or does it come from the database?
2. What is this hash based on?

Using PostgreSQL as the database.

Update: I noticed that the mismatch is not quite random. Here's what the database has:

```
CONSTRAINT user_id_refs_id_f15cc3cd FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES brandnew4.auth_user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

and here's the contraint that South tries to delete:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: constraint "user_id_refs_id_7e2ccc6bf15cc3cd" of relation "operatorInterface_ospreyuserprofile" does not exist
```

If you look closer at those constraint names:

```
        user_id_refs_id_f15cc3cd
user_id_refs_id_7e2ccc6bf15cc3cd
```

The 8-digit hex key in db is the same as last 8-digits of the *16-digit* hex key that South is looking for.

What's going on?

---

Update 2:
I tracked where the hash gets generated: https://github.com/django/django/commit/e4ea53677449cfc56a0093bfbd92cb482020bb1e

Why would South use the 64-bit version of the hash in one migration - and 32-bit version of the hash in the other?

South version 0.8.4 - I ran this on a completely new blank database.
Django version 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was: South is always looking in the `public` schema for the constraint names, and the migration was being applied in a schema other than `public`. Thus the mis-match.